# How to avoid "..." when convert a pandas matrix to string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example,

when the matrix is too wide, is there a way to suppress the "..." in the string format of pandas matrix to show all the detail of each column.

```
          adj_close_reg_1   ...         adj_low_reg_5
count     23954.000000      ...         23954.000000
mean          0.999850      ...             0.999501
std           0.019801      ...             0.043667
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with [set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.height', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

OR use:

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```